# I am not able to run rake db:migrate or bundle exec rake db:migrate in Rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rake, migrate

I am getting an error when trying to run rake db:migrate here:

http://pastie.org/2058143

I've re-installed Rake a few times now after downgrading from Rails 3.1 RC (bad idea to upgrade to that) to Rails 3.0, which is what I'm using now.

EDIT: This was solved by doing 'gem install rake -v=0.8.7', I think I forgot to do this after I uninstalled the previous version(s) and the Rakefile was missing.

Comment: Which version of rake are you using?

Comment: If I do a gem list, then it says "0.8.7" and inside of my Gemfile I do a gem 'rake', '0.8.7'

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution. Open your gemlock file and delete the entire write up there and save it. if you dont have rake 0.8.7 file on your application create a new app that uses rake 0.8.7 possibly with rails 3.0.8 then copy its rake file and replace it with your previous one